# Install org module on XEmacs

Tags: linux, emacs

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. I installed XEmacs 21.4 (patch 22)
I want to use org module BUT fail to install/configure it.
In my case I don't use .emacs but rather I have ~/.xemacs/custom.el where I keep all my settings. org module did not exist originally hence I did this:
git clone git://orgmode.org/org-mode.git
This created org-mode directory
Then I added these 2 lines to custom.el
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/susja/org-mode/lisp")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/susja/org-mode/contrib/lisp" t)
It did not load org module.
Then I ran M-x list-packages and did NOT see org package.
Could someone please help me to configure org module in order to handle .org files?
Thanks

Comment: This is the first XEmacs question that I think I have ever seen in 3.5 years of using Emacs, and this particular forum is the least used of all Emacs forums.  There are, however, a couple of high-powered Emacs users / developers who read this forum -- so perhaps someone may know the answer.  At some point, it may pay to switch to the latest stable release of the regular main-stream Emacs -- doing so will greatly increase the odds of obtaining answers from users who have the same version on their computers.  See also, http://emacs.stackexchange.com and https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs

Comment: All set now. Emacs forum explained me that XEmacs is obsolete and after I replaced it with GNU Emacs I'm all set. Thanks